# why this code is not showing product name in final output?

Tags: python, dataframe

This code only shows multiplied the price of products and not the product name. Also it displays"unnamed" in the final output.how to solve this?

```
newdf=df[['Product_name','Product_price']]
newdf=df.Product_price*2
newdf.to_csv('newsales.csv') 
newdf
```

Comment: Because you overwrote `newdf` in the 2nd line with just the `Product_price` part.

Answer (score 0):

In the second line, you need specify the column by doing that:

```
newdf['Product_name'] = df.Product_price * 2
```

or

```
newdf['Product_name'] = newdf['Product_name'] * 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newdf=df[['Product_name','Product_price']]
newdf['Product_price'] = newdf['Product_price']*2
newdf.to_csv('newsales.csv', index=False) 
newdf
```

Does it.